# Multiple else condition in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have python script with will read each IP from file and install agent on that IP using password, there are 5-6 passwords and if one password doesn't work it should try with other all passwords one by one. 
This is my script:

```
##Reading values from SucessfullIp.txt
with open('/root/nix_bsd_mac_inventory-master/SucessfullIp.txt') as f:
    ips = set(line.rstrip() for line in f)

##Reading Unique Ip's values 
with open("/root/nix_bsd_mac_inventory-master/Unique.txt") as fp:
        for line in fp:
                line = line.rstrip()
                ## Comparing unique ip's if ip is already has scanned
                if line in ips:
                        print('{}: Ip is Already Tried: '.format(line))
                else:
                ##Creating inventory.cfg file on the fly for each ip
                        f3 = open("/root/nix_bsd_mac_inventory-master/inventory.cfg", "w")
                        print "Processing Ip: " + line
                        f3.write("[device42_access]"  + "\n" +
                        "base_url = https://1.8.0.3"  + "\n" +
                        "username = uname"  + "\n" +
                        "secret = abcd"  + "\n" +
                        "[discover]"  + "\n" +
                        "cpu= true"  + "\n" +
                        "hardware = true"  + "\n" +
                        "memory = true"  + "\n" +
                        "[access]"+ "\n" +
                        "credentials = username:passowrd1" + "\n" + ##here we are giving credentials and we have 5-6 passwords
                        f3.close()
                        p = subprocess.Popen(["./d42_linux_autodisc_v620"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) ##This script will require inventory.cfg file created above
                        p1 = str(p.communicate())
                        if '1 devices were successfully added/updated' in p1:
                                print ('Sucessfull Completed Ip: ' +line)
                                f6 = open("/root/nix_bsd_mac_inventory-master/SucessfullIp.txt","a")
                                f6.write("\n"+line)
                                f6.close()
                        else:
                                print "Unsuccessfull"
                            ##here want it to check it with other passwords as well
```

Comment: There is no question in your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, How i can include multiple else to run script for 5-6 passwords if it doesn't work for one password it should run for other password and for last else it should say all password tried

Comment: You probably want a `for` loop over all passwords, which you `break` if any succeeds. `else` you might want to print the string `"Unsuccessful"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate over a list of your passwords and break out of the loop if one is successful.

You had a syntax error in the following snippet:

```
"credentials = username:passowrd1" + "\n" +
```

This should not end with a `+` as you are not concatenating anything else to the string.

It will be useful for you to look up [break, continue, and else statements](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) that you can use with loops as I have used them in the answer.

I have removed all of your comments, and added comments of my own to explain the logic.

```
with open("/root/nix_bsd_mac_inventory-master/Unique.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line in ips:
            print('{}: Ip is Already Tried: '.format(line))
            continue  # Continue means it will skip to the next password
        passwords = ['password1', 'password2', 'password3']
        for password in passwords:
            f3 = open("/root/nix_bsd_mac_inventory-master/inventory.cfg",
                      "w")
            print "Processing Ip: " + line
            f3.write("[device42_access]" + "\n" +
                     "base_url = https://1.8.0.3" + "\n" +
                     "username = uname" + "\n" +
                     "secret = abcd" + "\n" +
                     "[discover]" + "\n" +
                     "cpu= true" + "\n" +
                     "hardware = true" + "\n" +
                     "memory = true" + "\n" +
                     "[access]" + "\n" +
                     "credentials = username:" + password + "\n"  # Fixed typo here
            f3.close()
            p = subprocess.Popen(["./d42_linux_autodisc_v620"],
                                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            p1 = str(p.communicate())
            if '1 devices were successfully added/updated' in p1:
                print('Sucessfull Completed Ip: ' + line)
                f6 = open("/root/nix_bsd_mac_inventory-master/SucessfullIp.txt", "a")
                f6.write("\n" + line)
                f6.close()
                break  # If successful it breaks, so don't need an else
            print "Password %s Unsuccessfull" % password
        else:
            # This happens when there are no more passwords to attempt
            print "No passwords were successful"
```

Comment: there is else condition after : print('{}: Ip is Already Tried: '.format(line)) and in your script you didn't include else after continue.
Please check my above script and confirm if your script will work in this case as well

Comment: line = line.rstrip()
                if line in ips:
                        print('{}: Ip is Already Tried: '.format(line))
                        #continue
                else:
                for password in passwords:
                        f3 = open("/root/nix_bsd_mac_inventory-master/inventory.cfg", "w")
                        print "Check with 1st Password :"
                        print "Processing Ip: " + line

Comment: I have made changes suggested by you and getting error:
[root@10 nix_bsd_mac_inventory-master]# python s2.py
  File "s2.py", line 43
    for password in passwords:
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: You haven't copied it properly. That is a syntax error regarding indentation. You should fix the indentation.

Comment: indentation error is fixed but because of else condition it's running as expected, can you please check my above script and give your inputs

Comment: Well no I can't really. It's not formatted and you haven't explained what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please check my script which i paste at first time it is in formatted way

Comment: Thanks for help, issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a for loop and a single else:

```
for password in list_of_password:
    ...
    "credentials = username:" + password + "\n"
    ...
    if '1 devices were successfully added/updated' in p1:
        ...
        break
else:
    print "Unsuccessfull"
```

Comment: The for-else is probably the good way to go, but please fix your line at `credential = ...`

Comment: list_of_password is array ?

Comment: @AkashSarpate in Python we have no array, only lists